# Sequentially run multiple scripts from one 'master' script

Tags: powershell

I have plenty of ps1 scipts which I execute one by one manually, they have `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` in their syntax so if something goes wrong they shall stop.

What I want help with is to create a ps1 script that can run all of these scripts sequentially. So if one script fails the "master script" must stop and not continue with next script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 files like:

*1WriteHello.ps1*

```
Write-Host "Hello " -NoNewLine
```

*2WriteWorld.ps1*

```
Write-Host "World!"
```

*3WriteError.ps1*

```
Write-Error "Something went wrong."
```

*4WriteANumber.ps1*

```
Write-Host "123"
```

You can run it with command:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; Get-Item 'C:\Path\*.ps1' |% { & $_.FullName }
```

In your example:

```
$Scripts = 'D:\temp\download_script.ps1', 'D:\temp\upload_script.ps1', 'D:\temp\reset_scripts.ps1'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$Scripts |% { & $_ }
```

Comment: You may want to sort the files you get, as not every file system gives you files ordered alphabetically (especially on non-Windows systems).

Comment: Also worth noting that `%` is an alias of [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)